How to convert shapefiles to DWG with text annotations correctly
I am trying to convert shapefiles (containing geometry and attributes like parcel numbers, street names, etc.) into DWG format. The DWG needs to include not only the geometries (points, lines, polygons) but also the text annotations (e.g., parcel numbers and street names) as visible labels or annotations in AutoCAD Map 3D.
I have access to the following software:
AutoCAD Map 3D 2020
ArcMap 10.4
QGIS 3.28
Despite several attempts, the text annotations either don’t show up in the final DWG file, or the file is completely empty in AutoCAD. Below are the steps I have already tried:

In ArcMap 10.4.1:
Enabled labels on the shapefile layer and configured them to show parcel numbers.
Converted the labels to annotations using Convert Labels to Annotation (stored in the map document).
Exported the shapefile to DWG using the Export to CAD tool.
Issue:

In AutoCAD Map 3D, the exported DWG file contains the geometry, but the annotations (text labels) are missing.

In QGIS 3.28:
Loaded the shapefile and enabled labeling based on the attribute containing the parcel numbers.
Tried exporting the layer using Export > Save Features As..., selecting AutoCAD DXF format.

Issue:
The resulting DXF file is either empty or missing the text annotations when opened in AutoCAD Map 3D.

In AutoCAD Map 3D 2020:
Imported the shapefile using the Data Connect tool.
Ensured the attribute data was included.
Attempted to configure labels within AutoCAD based on the imported attribute data.

Issue:
While the geometries import correctly, I cannot figure out how to create visible text annotations from the attributes (e.g., parcel numbers).
Question:
How can I successfully convert SHP files to DWG format, ensuring that both geometries and text annotations (parcel numbers, street names, etc.) appear correctly in AutoCAD Map 3D?
Are additional tools, plugins, or workflows I need to consider in ArcMap, QGIS, or AutoCAD? I need detailed step-by-step solution for any of these tools.

You have three questions here, violating the One question per Question doctrine. Your ArcGIS procedure is flawed because shapefiles can't store annotation. 10.4 was retired nearly three years ago, so it's unlikely that there are many folks able to reproduce your environment, but you should convert the shapefile to file geodatabase, then try adding anno to that, then exporting.

In Map3D, using MAPCONNECT, after labeling features use MAPLABEL2ANN to convert the feature labels to AutoCAD objects.

Thank you for your comment @Vince, it helped me solve the issue!
